# How to delete all/some restify routes and add new

Tags: node.js, restify

I have a JSON config file which specifies API end-points. I read it on app load and iterate through its keys, like this

```
server[type](config.path, function (req, res, next) {

});
```

Now, I am looking for a way to remove that route from server. I mean delete the API I just created. Is there any way by which it can be done? I checked the docs but couldn't find anything related to this.

I tried removing keys in `server.routes`. But it creates new keys with different name and I am not sure why it creates. for example if I delete a route `getusers` from `server.routes`, a new key is created like `server.routes.getusers234234` (some random number appended).

Comment: Why would you do that? I've never had a project that required me to change routes on the fly. Once, I read a Netflix blog post where they tried to do something similar and they introduced a memory leak... (So, this might not be the best way/idea to do this)

Comment: I see. But just to understand how this works. I mean If I can create routes on the fly, why can't I remove/change them! I haven't looked at the source yet, but routes seems nothing but a map of `type+api` so removing them, or changing them should be easy thing to do.

Comment: Can you give me an example use case?

Comment: Okay, what I am trying to implement is a config based API which can be changed without restarting the application. I would call a function on specific event, which would delete previous routes and add new ones. each route would act as per settings in that config file I mentioned.

Comment: What Max mentioned about Netflix from memory is not entirely correct. They moved away from Express to Restify as Express was leaking when they where trying to remove routes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to remove a route in Restify would, I believe, be to scan `server.routes.mounts` for any routes you want to remove and then pass each of those route objects to `server.rm`.